# How to incorporate biometric authentication in an app that uses Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

Currently, my Flutter App uses Firebase email & password authentication, I want to keep this but also enable the use of biometric authentication.

So far the only solution I've seen is encrypting the user's email and password on the device and if the biometric authentication is successful then you decrypt the email and password and then use those to authenticate with Firebase.

Is this the best way to handle it right now?
What other solutions are there?

Comment: My experience with Firebase Auth, is that you wouldn't need to persist it. Firebase Auth handles that for you, under the hood. Once the user is logged in, they stay logged in (and even across devices, because Firebase stores the current user in Keychain (and whatever Android calls it), not in SharedPreferences or NSUserDefaults.

I think you'd really just need to do the biometric auth to get to the protected sections in your app.

Comment: @JaredAnderton Right, but if the user logs out at any point, I would then need to ask them for their email, password, & prompt them for the biometric authentication.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But, Firebase auth logins are persistent. It's not like a token expiring. It would be an intentional action of the user to log out, in my opinion, removing the need to hold on to credentials. However, if you do want to be able to log them back in with biometrics (after an intentional logout), then yes, you would need to use store the credentials. There is a handy package I've used for this in the past, and you'll need to capture the creds at the time the setup the account (or do the login) (Google wont expose them back to you): https://pub.dev/packages/biometric_storage